# Any free tool to change color of an image

Tags: images, colors, processing, gimp

HI,

Is there any tool which can easily change color of an image?
I heard of gimp. But I can't figure out how to use it to change color of an image (e.g. change  the color from white to blue).

Comment: @n179911, what kind of image? SVG/EPS/AI or TIFF/GIF/JPG?

Comment: And what platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GIMP, to change white to blue:

- Open the image file
- menu Colors/Map/Color Exchange
- Press the colour selection for "From Color". Set R, G and B to all 255. Press OK button.
- Press the colour selection for "To Color". Set R and G to all 0. Set B to 255. Press OK button.
- Press OK button.

White and black are special... If you want to translate all other colours then:

- Open the image file
- menu Colors/Hue-Saturation
- Press "Master" button
- Drag the Hue slider

Answer (score 3):

[Paint.Net](http://www.getpaint.net) is a free and easy to use photo editor.  It's my recommendation for those who don't want to afford Photoshop and want something easier to use than Gimp (which can be daunting).

You can find help using it [here](http://paintdotnet.forumer.com/viewforum.php?f=29).

Comment: Yes, i tried Gimp once (coming from a Photoshop background), and I was TOTALLY lost in Gimp... the menus, tool-windows, palettes, everything was all over and didn't conform to any kind of standards that i saw. (maybe it conforms to some *nix standard?) Paint.NET on the other hand has menus and windows and palettes conforming to Windows usuals and very close to Photoshop's and is hence much easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

The GIMP is what you want, but learning how to use it is far beyond the scope of this site.

There are innumerable tutorials for simple effects like this; I would suggest firing up your favorite search engine, and looking for "photo retouching".

Comment: I think that GIMP is an excellent solution.  Yes, it looks daunting but just check out youtube for some great tutorials and you'll be adjusting the colors of your photos (and more I bet) in no time.

Comment: I've been using Photoshop since v3 ... When the Mac Quadra was king and 72MiB of RAM cost more than my car ... The biggest problem I have with the GIMP is just remembering where things are.  You can do anything that PS will do (and more), but the menus are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

[**PhotoFiltre**](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/photofiltre.html) - free, small, fast and feature packed and easy to use

and here is a little video tutorial: [how to change colours with PhotoFiltre](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiaqJPCtUMY)

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite is [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)  It has a fairly robust feature set, and it's free.

Answer (score 0):

MooO ImageInColors 1.09 (Free)
Convert Images into Various Color Tones.

http://www.moo0.com/software/ImageInColors/

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find Paint.NET's [Recolor Tool](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/paint.net/doc/2.6/Help/en/RecolorTool.html) to be quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Faststone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDetail.htm). Download from [here](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDownload.htm) or [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download%5Ffaststone%5Fimage%5Fviewer/)

A screenshot of its 'Enhance colors' utility:

[image]